# How to authenticate a mobile app with no user credentials?

Tags: authentication, mobile, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I have a mobile game that interacts with an API. I want this API **to only be called from this mobile app**.
It's simple to explain but on the other hand, *its **simplicity** makes it **chaotic***.

**There are no users, therefore no user credentials**. It's an open game that requests an image from the API.

Things I don't want to implement:

1. `Hardcoded` secret/apikey/token etc. -> Nothing must be hardcoded
2. `One Time Password`-> No OTP via SMS, Email, push notifications or any user interaction.
3. `Device ID` or `Advertising I`D -> Good solution but any other apps also get this ID then call my API. Plus, any attacker can send anything as Device ID, right? So how can I verify this device ID is a real identifier for an existing device?

Game developed with `Unity3D`.
API consists of an `AWS API Gateway` and `Lambda`. I am considering using AWS `Cognito` as an auth server.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I suggest you to check this option for Android devices https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604018/1027846

Answer (score 4):

### THE API SERVER LOCK TO THE MOBILE APP

> I have a mobile game that interacts with an API. I want this API to only be called from this mobile app. It's simple to explain but on the other hand, its simplicity makes me chaotic.

In Software Development it's common that things that are easy to explain may be very hard to implement, and this is one of that cases.

So what you want to achieve is to lock your API server to your mobile app, or by other words to ensure that you APi server only responds to requests comming from your genuine and un-tampered mobile app you have uploaded to the official stores.

You mention that are no users:

> There are no users, therefore no user credentials. It's a open game that requests an image from the API.

But I think you may want to say that you don't have **Authenticated Users**, and even you had them you would only identify **Who** is in the request, not **What** is doing the request.

This is a common misconception among developers, no matter if junior or senior, thus it's important to properly clear it out in order you can develop an effective secure solution for your mobile app.

#### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

I wrote a series of articles around API and Mobile security, and one of them contains a good description on this difference, the article [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) is the one you want to read to better understand the difference between **Who** and **What** is accessing your API server, but I will extract here the main take aways from it:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?
>
> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

Think about the **Who** as the user an API server will be able to Authenticate and Authorize access to the data, and think about the **What** as the software making that request in behalf of the user.

So in your situation you are not worried about the **Who** in the request, instead you want to know **What** is doing the request so that you can lock your API server to your genuine mobile app.

#### Hardcoded Identifiers

> Hardcoded secret/apikey/token etc. -> Nothing must be hardcoded

That's a very wise decison, because from the moment you release a mobile app, anything sensitive date inside it must be considered as compromised because a lot of open source tools exist to help anyone to perform static and dynamic analysis on a mobile app binary to extract that data and/or change behavior of the app. Examples of this type of tools are:

[MobSF - Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

#### Runtime Identifiers

> Device ID or Advertising ID -> Good solution but any other apps also get this ID then call my API. Plus, any attacker can send anything as Device ID, right? So how can I verify this device ID is a real identifier for an existing device?

This identifiers are easily manipulated/extracted during run-time with framework like Frida or Cydia, thus they are open to exploited by an attacker as you already guessed.

Now if you are referring to more advanced identifiers like the Android SafetyNet and/or the [iOS DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck), then I want to call your attention to some details:

**Android SafetyNET**

You may want to read my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742965/6454622) to the question *Android equivalent of ios devicecheck* that goes in great detail about what it is and what is not.

But in short it was not designed to be used as a stand-alone defence, as per [Google own statement](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation):

> The goal of this API is to provide you with confidence about the integrity of a device running your app. You can then obtain additional signals using the standard Android APIs. You should use the SafetyNet Attestation API as an additional in-depth defense signal as part of an anti-abuse system, not as the sole anti-abuse signal for your app.

**iOS DeviceCheck**

Apple’s [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) solution is primarily designed to validate the identity and track record of a physical mobile device without the need to track any personal information about the device or its user:

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs, you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining user privacy. You might use this data to identify devices that have already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide,...

And as they also say you can also use it for marking a device as cfraudlent:

> ...or to flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent. The DeviceCheck APIs also let you verify that the token you receive comes from an authentic Apple device on which your app has been downloaded.

But bear in the words they use: **to flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent**. So it's up to you to determine the device status, but remember that knowing a device is rooted or jail broken it's not the same as knowing **What** is making the request to the API server.

So should I use them?
Yes, because defense is all about adding as much layers as you can afford, but this will not solve your main issue, that is to know **What** is making the request to your API server.

#### Authentication Server

> I am considering using AWS Cognito as an auth server.

No matter if Cognito or any other Authentication server they excel in identify, authenticate and authorize **Who** is in the request but they don't know how to do the same for **What** is doing the request.

### A POSSIBLE SOLUTION

> I want this API to only be called from this mobile app.
> So how can I verify this device ID is a real identifier for an existing device?

In order to know that **What** is doing the request is indeed your genuine and unmodified instance of your mobile app you need to use the Mobile App Attestation concept, that I describe in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605789/6454622) to the question *How to secure an API REST for mobile app?*, specially the sections for *Securing the API Server* and *A Possible Better Solution*.

### DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

I cannot finish my reply without referencing the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

Comment: This is all great but are there any libraries or code that will do this? This is all boilerplate code so I’d think it would make sense that there be something like that as most people implementing this for the first time will inevitably accidentally miss something resulting in security vulnerabilities. This stuff seems to be hard to find. So hard that I’m guessing very few people do this properly.

Comment: Security is indeed very hard and open source libraries that do all of this in one don't exist as of I am aware, but a lot can be done by using open source code in conjunction with in-house code, but the amount of time and skills required will be too much for the majority, thus they will search for a commercial solution, or just do a subset of the security layers that are easy to implement with current open source libraries and tools.

Comment: so since I wrote that comment, i've come across the following that can help: Firebase AppCheck, and Approov. both look like they provide the client and server implementation of the attestation (ie iOS Device check) of the app on the users device and possibly the transport security. Once i've implemented in my app and tested it all out ill write up a separate answer to provide the details. Given how common this problem is and how little support there is for this, i'm guessing the majority of apps out there that use web services are insecure in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this exact implementation, but I think you could do something like the following:

1) Configure your API Gateway to use IAM auth (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/)

2) Using Cognito, you should configure your Identity Pool to allow unauthenticated users and adjust the permissions of your Cognito unauthenticated identities accordingly (some info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html)

3) You can use the Amplify SDK to retrieve temporary AWS credentials of an unauthenticated user in your app and hit your API Gateway (good steps here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/711#issuecomment-414100476 and more about Amplify here: https://docs.amplify.aws/)