# How does Google's API key restrictions work for mobile apps?

Tags: api, restriction

I'm trying to find an updated answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465559/restrict-api-requests-to-only-my-own-mobile-app) question from 2012.

Googles API keys can be restricted for urls, ip addresses, or mobile apps. 
[image: Google Api Key Restrictions]

How does their restriction work? Is it just a header that gives the bundle ID which could very easily be faked by a hacker? Or is there something clever going on that can't be faked as easily?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

“S” — Security!
Right now it seems like SDK just adds `X-iOS-Bundle-Identifier` header with the app Bundle ID to every geocoding request :(
So even a baby-hacker could use your Google key anytime in his own apps or services.

```
curl --header "X-iOS-Bundle-Identifier: com.attacked.Application" "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.4134391,-122.1513073&key=[STOLEN-GOOGLE-KEY]"
```