# How to secure my api call (with authentication) in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an api which allows calling without any authentication (get call). If I have an app deployed in Google Play store. May I know if there is any way to secure the api call only allowing call by my app in the Google Play Store?

Comment: Consider editing this question and making it clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict API requests to only my own mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465559/restrict-api-requests-to-only-my-own-mobile-app)