# How to securely communicate to a server via Android App

Tags: android, security, kotlin

I am setting up an app which will communicate to a server.

I need to check if a user performed a certain action in app and then pass it to server. But how to pass it securely? It's easy to check the network log and see the details of the endpoint and parameters. How to pass the constant value only from the app across to the server without someone making it hit the end point via other than the android app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465559/restrict-api-requests-to-only-my-own-mobile-app